# How to parse JSONArray with in JSON Array in Android /Java?

Tags: java, android, json

I had a JSONObject as below, in which I had an JSONArray within JSONArray. Can anyone help me how to parse that in Android / java ?

```
{
 "2015": [
        [
            {
                "poster": "cr.jpg",
                "name": "CR"
            },
            {
                "poster": "pm.jpg",
                "name": "Pm"
            },
            {
                "poster": "uv.jpg",
                "name": "UVn"
            }
        ]

    ]
}
```

Comment: ait has key value pairs: Key 2015 value: Array of elements.  Try this link http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-json-parsing-tutorial/ if you still getting problems post them here. We will be more then happy to solve a problem but you are just pushing it now.

Comment: How to parse through this JSON  ?  I tried I got initial JSON array by calling like below: JSONbject json = new JSONObject("jsonSting"); <br> JSONArray outerArray  = json.getJSONArray("2015"); <br> After this how to get the internal array to parse json object  in it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could first get the JSON object with :

```
JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonStr);
```

and then get the JSONArray within it using :

```
 JSONArray jsonarr = jsonObj.getJSONArray("2015");
```

then use a loop to iterate through the array elements :

```
for (int i=0;i<jsonarr.length();i++) {
JSONObject item1 = new JSONObject();
String poster = item1.getString("poster");
String name = item1.getString("name");
//Store this in a hashmap maybe, depending on how you want it
}
```

for further details you could check out this link too : http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-json-parsing-tutorial/

Answer (score 0):

```
JSONArray array2015 = yourJsonObject.getJSONArray("2015")[0];
```